# Taking data from my computer and putting it on my switch

Tags: sd-card, nintendo

I wanted to test something but I don't know what will happened and if it'll break my switch. So I'm curious to know if any knows, if I have a game that I made and I put in on a microSD card and then put in in my switch what will happen. I don't have home-brew or anything so it's a normal vanilla switch

I've never done anything like this before and I don't wanna break my switch because I won't be able to get a new one

Answer (score 0):

Nothing will happen. It is like putting pictures on your USB Flash drive, inserting it in your computer and worrying it will burn. Your Switch won't just execute any program, it actually doesn't even know what to do with most files and will simply not load them, even if you open them.

You won't break your Switch. But I highly doubt you made a game yourself and actually don't know how to run it. You probably downloaded something from the net. In that case: Also won't execute without Homebrew. Nintendo thought of this already.

Comment: alrighty follow up question, would there be a way for it to read it or do I need Homebrew?

Comment: @NoahDavis Homebrew, otherwise it would be easy to simply copy a friends copy of the game. That's the whole purpose of Homebrew anyways. Alternatively you could simply buy the game.

Comment: Ok it's not a game for the switch that's why I asked, but thank you.